# How to increase FPS for my face mask detection project using OpenCV?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras, raspberry-pi

I'm building a face mask detector on my Raspberry Pi but the problem is the video is super laggy. Is there any way I can get the video output to be more than 1 FPS? I'm new to Python and am using this code I found online to test if it works or not. When I use the Pi camera normally I get a good amount of FPS, but when using the mask detector it gives me almost 0 FPS. Any help would be appreciated!

[Here is my code](https://pastebin.com/6u9SifuM)

```
from gpiozero import Buzzer, LED
from time import sleep
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
trig = 18
red = LED(14)
green = LED(15)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(trig,GPIO.OUT)
buzzer = GPIO.PWM(trig, 1000)
# import the necessary packages
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os
 
def detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet):
    # grab the dimensions of the frame and then construct a blob
    # from it
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (300, 300),
        (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))
 
    # pass the blob through the network and obtain the face detections
    faceNet.setInput(blob)
    detections = faceNet.forward()
 
    # initialize our list of faces, their corresponding locations,
    # and the list of predictions from our face mask network
    faces = []
    locs = []
    preds = []
 
    # loop over the detections
    for i in range(0, detections.shape[3]):
        # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with
        # the detection
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
 
        # filter out weak detections by ensuring the confidence is
        # greater than the minimum confidence
        if confidence > args["confidence"]:
            # compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for
            # the object
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
 
            # ensure the bounding boxes fall within the dimensions of
            # the frame
            (startX, startY) = (max(0, startX), max(0, startY))
            (endX, endY) = (min(w - 1, endX), min(h - 1, endY))
 
            # extract the face ROI, convert it from BGR to RGB channel
            # ordering, resize it to 224x224, and preprocess it
            face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
            face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
            face = img_to_array(face)
            face = preprocess_input(face)
            face = np.expand_dims(face, axis=0)
 
            # add the face and bounding boxes to their respective
            # lists
            faces.append(face)
            locs.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))
 
    # only make a predictions if at least one face was detected
    if len(faces) > 0:
        # for faster inference we'll make batch predictions on *all*
        # faces at the same time rather than one-by-one predictions
        # in the above `for` loop
        preds = maskNet.predict(faces)
 
    # return a 2-tuple of the face locations and their corresponding
    # locations
    return (locs, preds)
 
# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-f", "--face", type=str,
    default="face_detector",
    help="path to face detector model directory")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", type=str,
    default="mask_detector.model",
    help="path to trained face mask detector model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
 
# load our serialized face detector model from disk
print("[INFO] loading face detector model...")
prototxtPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"], "deploy.prototxt"])
weightsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"],
    "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"])
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)
 
# load the face mask detector model from disk
print("[INFO] loading face mask detector model...")
maskNet = load_model(args["model"])
 
# initialize the video stream and allow the camera sensor to warm up
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
#vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=True).start()
time.sleep(1.0)
 
# loop over the frames from the video stream
while True:
    # grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it
    # to have a maximum width of 400 pixels
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)
 
    # detect faces in the frame and determine if they are wearing a
    # face mask or not
    (locs, preds) = detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet)
 
    # loop over the detected face locations and their corresponding
    # locations
    for (box, pred) in zip(locs, preds):
        # unpack the bounding box and predictions
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
        (incorrect, mask, nomask) = pred
 
        # determine the class label and color we'll use to draw
        # the bounding box and text
        # label = "Mask" if mask > withoutMask else "No Mask"
        # color = (0, 255, 0) if label == "Mask" else (0, 0, 255)
 
        if (mask > nomask):
            label = "Mask"
            color = (0, 255, 0)
            buzzer.stop()
            red.off()
            green.on()
            
        elif (nomask > mask):
            label = "No Mask"
            color = (0, 0, 255)
            buzzer.start(10)
            time.sleep(1)
            green.off()
            red.on()
            
        elif (incorrect > nomask):
            label = "Incomplete"
            color = (0, 255, 255)
            buzzer.start(10)
            time.sleep(1)
            green.off()
            red.on()
            
 
 
        # include the probability in the label
        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, max(incorrect, mask, nomask) * 100)
 
        # display the label and bounding box rectangle on the output
        # frame
        cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 10),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)
 
    # show the output frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
 
    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
 
# do a bit of cleanup
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Deeplearning Machine Models are known to be commonly slow while parsing an image. Have you tried making an Opencv haarcascade? Maybe try compressing the resolution of the frames, Tutorial over here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-compress-images-using-python-and-pil/

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: I have now edited the answer. My best technique would be to compress the frames or hosting a python server for the processing.